# What the method to manage Cleanup Code loop for a cumulative (single) value packed into two values using SIMD?

Tags: c++, loops, simd, sse2

Let say I manage a `__m128d` variable called `v_phase`, which is calculated as

```
index 0 : load prev phase
index 1 : phase += newValue
index 2 : phase += newValue
index 3 : phase += newValue
index 4 : phase += newValue
...
```

This is the basic code:

```
__m128d v_phase;

// load prev cumulated mPhase to v_phase (as mPhase, mPhase + nextValue)

for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < blockSize; sampleIndex += 2, pValue += 2) {
    // function with phase

    // update pValue increment (its not linear)

    // phase increment: v_phase += newValue
}

// cleanup code
if (blockSize % 2 == 0) {
    mPhase = v_phase.m128d_f64[0];
}
```

The fact is: if `blockSize` is even, it works fine: it will sum in the last loop iteration **two more phase values**, and take the `v_phase.m128d_f64[0]` (i.e. the first of the new two addition).

But what if the `blockSize` is odd? I'll simply need the `v_phase.m128d_f64[1]` of last iteration **without sum two more phase values**.

I could use `sampleIndex < blockSize - 1`, but this will move the logic `// function with phase` within the `// cleanup code` (which I don't like it so much).

Place a if within the loop is somethings I'll avoid (branc prediction; since I'm using SIMD, I'm optimizing code, this will slow).

Any tips?

Here's a more "complete" example:

```
double phase = mPhase;

__m128d v_pB = _mm_setr_pd(0.0, pB[0]);
v_pB = _mm_mul_pd(v_pB, v_radiansPerSampleBp0);
__m128d v_pC = _mm_setr_pd(0.0, pC[0]);
v_pC = _mm_mul_pd(v_pC, v_radiansPerSample);

__m128d v_pB_prev = _mm_setr_pd(0.0, 0.0);
v_pB_prev = _mm_mul_pd(v_pB_prev, v_radiansPerSampleBp0);
__m128d v_pC_prev = _mm_setr_pd(0.0, 0.0);
v_pC_prev = _mm_mul_pd(v_pC_prev, v_radiansPerSample);

__m128d v_phaseAcc1;
__m128d v_phaseAcc2;
__m128d v_phase = _mm_set1_pd(phase);

// phase
v_phaseAcc1 = _mm_add_pd(v_pB, v_pC);
v_phaseAcc1 = _mm_max_pd(v_phaseAcc1, v_boundLower);
v_phaseAcc1 = _mm_min_pd(v_phaseAcc1, v_boundUpper);
v_phaseAcc2 = _mm_add_pd(v_pB_prev, v_pC_prev);
v_phaseAcc2 = _mm_max_pd(v_phaseAcc2, v_boundLower);
v_phaseAcc2 = _mm_min_pd(v_phaseAcc2, v_boundUpper);
v_phase = _mm_add_pd(v_phase, v_phaseAcc1);
v_phase = _mm_add_pd(v_phase, v_phaseAcc2);

for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < blockSize; sampleIndex += 2, pB += 2, pC += 2) {
    // code that will use v_phase

    // phase increment
    v_pB = _mm_loadu_pd(pB + 1);
    v_pB = _mm_mul_pd(v_pB, v_radiansPerSampleBp0);
    v_pC = _mm_loadu_pd(pC + 1);
    v_pC = _mm_mul_pd(v_pC, v_radiansPerSample);

    v_pB_prev = _mm_load_pd(pB);
    v_pB_prev = _mm_mul_pd(v_pB_prev, v_radiansPerSampleBp0);
    v_pC_prev = _mm_load_pd(pC);
    v_pC_prev = _mm_mul_pd(v_pC_prev, v_radiansPerSample);

    v_phaseAcc1 = _mm_add_pd(v_pB, v_pC);
    v_phaseAcc1 = _mm_max_pd(v_phaseAcc1, v_boundLower);
    v_phaseAcc1 = _mm_min_pd(v_phaseAcc1, v_boundUpper);
    v_phaseAcc2 = _mm_add_pd(v_pB_prev, v_pC_prev);
    v_phaseAcc2 = _mm_max_pd(v_phaseAcc2, v_boundLower);
    v_phaseAcc2 = _mm_min_pd(v_phaseAcc2, v_boundUpper);
    v_phase = _mm_add_pd(v_phase, v_phaseAcc1);
    v_phase = _mm_add_pd(v_phase, v_phaseAcc2);
}

// cleanup code
if (blockSize % 2 == 0) {
    mPhase = v_phase.m128d_f64[0];
}
else {
    ??? if odd?
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but the problem seems unclear. For example, what does "pValue increment" mean? You might want to add a [mcve].

Comment: A general advice I can give is (1) rearrange your loop sections and (2) initialize phase to a lower value, corresponding to iteration -1. But cannot be sure it's useful without seeing all the details.

Comment: "initialize phase to a lower value, corresponding to iteration -1" I can't. Theres always a starting point where its "0", -1 doesn't exist

Comment: @anatolyg: I've add more code, it should be clear now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output also the *previous* `v_phase` from your loop, in addition to last one. That is, before updating your `v_phase`, store the previous one:

```
__m128d prev_v_phase;
for (...) {
    ...
    prev_v_phase = v_phase;
    v_phase = _mm_add_pd(v_phase, v_phaseAcc1);
    v_phase = _mm_add_pd(v_phase, v_phaseAcc2);
}

// cleanup code
if (blockSize % 2 == 0) {
    mPhase = v_phase.m128d_f64[0];
}
else {
    mPhase = prev_v_phase.m128d_f64[1];
}
```

This will fail if the loop doesn't perform any iterations at all (then `prev_v_phase` will be uninitialized), but it's a case where performance is not important, so easy to handle.

Comment: It seems to works. Maybe a bit "too complicated" for a common value increment? :)